# XML to String in C#

Tags: xml

So I have the following XML file as an `XmlDocument xmlDoc;` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<metars>
  <status>success</status>
  <data>
    <metar>KPIE 111653Z 07006KT 10SM CLR 26/13 A3024</metar>
  </data>
</metars>
```

And now just simply want the text between `<metar></metar>` as a String. But how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [XPath query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""yes""?>
<metars>
  <status>success</status>
  <data>
    <metar>KPIE 111653Z 07006KT 10SM CLR 26/13 A3024</metar>
  </data>
</metars>";

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(s);
            string t = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//metar")?.InnerXml;

            Console.WriteLine(t);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> KPIE 111653Z 07006KT 10SM CLR 26/13 A3024

The `?.` uses a [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) just in case there was no element "<metar>".